# How can I tell if OpenGL has finished rendering the current frame?

Tags: android, opengl-es2

If I make a call to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#requestRender() from my game loop, how can I tell when OpenGL has finished rendering?

I don't want to make a call to `requestRender()` again in the next frame until the previous frame has finished rendering.

Sorry for the basic question I'm new to opengl and trying to switch to it from canvas.

Also, is GLSurfaceView.requestRender() a blocking call?

Comment: "I don't want to make a call to requestRender() again in the next frame until the previous frame has finished rendering." Can you explain why? Its probably better to let OpenGL handle the draw queue and frame dropping.

Comment: @RoyT. My (probably naive) thinking was that I want to ensure that the whole frame is drawn in a consistent state. My updateGameState() call is made in the main game loop thread, and I only want OpenGL to draw when all sprites have been updated to the current time. I was planning to store the positions and rotations of sprites before drawing them asynchronously with OpenGL (and then recalling updateGameState() on the CPU while the current frame is being rendered on the GPU).

Comment: Sounds like a good way to have choppy frame rates.

Comment: @Byte56 Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You said you only want openGL to draw once all the sprites have been updated. That means your frame rate will be dependent on your update loop. Ideally, the update loop should be allowed to vary in it's update rate as needed, the frame rate should not. I think you're making the two threads too dependent on each other.

Comment: @Byte56 isn't the frame rate very much dependant on the update loop though? what's the point in rendering a new frame if nothing moved?

Comment: Sprites aren't the only thing that moves. The camera moves, the GUI updates, animations play, etc. If you know you can update fast enough, then just put the update loop before the draw call. Then run them in the same thread.

Comment: "*I only want OpenGL to draw when all sprites have been updated to the current time*" - just create a double-buffered context and this will be handled automatically for you.  Update all sprites, draw them, swap buffers.  GL drivers are asynchronous and pipelined to begin with, so you don't need any software tricks to get this behaviour; it just happens for free (in fact a surefire way to break it is by trying software tricks that go outside of the way it's designed to work).

Comment: @mh01 Thanks, do you have a link to an example? I still think there's a potential issue - if the update() call is very fast, then the previous frame will still be rendering when calling requestRender(), even in a double buffered context couldn't that still be an issue?

Comment: This focusses on D3D but is a good read as the principles are the same: http://c0de517e.blogspot.com/2008/04/gpu-part-1.html - you don't need to worry about whether or not the previous frame is rendering; your commands and data are copied over so you can freely change them, and there will be a max number of buffered frames (typically 3) after which things will stall until rendering completes.  If you're still worried about this, just stick in a glFinish, but do try it without one first.

Answer (score 3):

Jimmy Shelter is right. When you implement a GLSurfaceView.Renderer the onDrawFrame() handles the game loop for you. See this link:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/android-game-development-switching-from.html

If you need data on the progression of the loop put a counter within your Renderer class in your onDrawFrame() method:

```
public class GlRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

 private int counter = 0;
 @Override
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
      counter++;
}}
```

Depending on the amount of calculations you have going on in your loop you may need to slow it down to 60fps otherwise your animations may be occurring too frequently.

```
public class GlRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

 private long loopStart =0;
 private long loopEnd = 0;
 private long loopRunTime = 0;
 private final int FPS = (1000/60);

 @Override
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
      loopStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if(loopRunTime < FPS )
 {
 Thread.sleep(FPS - loopRunTime);
  }

 loopEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
 loopRunTime = ((loopEnd - loopStart));
}
}
```

Comment: Depending on what platform you're on the timer used by Thread.Sleep may not be accurate enough to get smooth frame rates. I'd go with enabling vsync instead if possible. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Swap_Interval